# Word meaning "not normal, but relatively normal in context"

Tags: single-word-requests

Here's a passage from a story I vaguely remember:

> The ritual involves gruesome acts like self-mutilation or
>   sacrifice, but also some __ steps like standing on a skyscraper and
>   humming for three hours.

I'm looking for a single word that I can fill in the blank. I've been suggested phrases like "relatively normal", but I am pretty sure that this was a single word.

Comment: A passage like that in fiction probably wouldn't be so explicit. Compare: "The ritual involves self-mutilation, human sacrifice, and [humming "Sugar, Sugar" for three hours atop a skyscraper](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArsonMurderAndJaywalking)." Show, don't tell.

Comment: I think any of the several good suggestions below (benign, mundane, etc.) would still call for a qualifier like *rather more* or *comparatively*. If someone had me stand atop a skyscraper and hum for three hours - even if that was the worst they did to me - I'd hardly describe the experience as *benign*.

Comment: The passage plainly calls for a word that lends it a mildly ironic tone; no qualifier is required with the right word.

Answer (score 2):

**Less extreme** could be another option.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to go with something like **intermediate** or perhaps **lesser** for that passage.

Answer (score 1):

By comparison, standing on a skyscraper etc is *benign*.

Answer (score 0):

How about [mundane](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mundane)?

1. ...
2. common; ordinary; banal; unimaginative.

Answer (score 0):

***conventional***
con·ven·tion·al/kənˈvenCHənl/
Adjective:
    Based on or in accordance with what is generally done or believed.

[convention (norm)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_%28norm%29) 
A convention is a set of agreed, stipulated or generally accepted standards, norms, social norms or criteria, often taking the form of a custom.
'... it is conventional in many societies that strangers being introduced shake hands.'

alternatives: *customary*, *the-done-thing*, *en vogue*, *the usual* ...

I would suggest that you revise your interpretation of *normal* itself. Consider this: 'In our practice, average is normal.' If a patient is underweight by WHO standards, but close to the average for his demographic, the patient's weight is considered normal.

Answer (score -1):

Compared to self-mutilation, standing on a skyscraper and humming is ***prosaic***:

> **prosaic**, *adjective*: belonging to or suitable for the everyday world [MW]

You could also say that it's ***[humdrum](http://www.wordnik.com/words/humdrum)*** (another synonym for *prosaic*).

Comment: Dear downvoter, please consult the [corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for the use of _prosaic_ in this context.